# How to Show Div for Button Only When Loading

Tags: angular, angularjs, user-interface, loading

This is an Angular.js UI and I have status bars for tasks. When a user selects "Complete" in a mat-menu the bar switches to "Complete" but there is some latency.

I am have created a "Loading" status bar with a spinner using bootstrap. I want to make it so the loading status bar replaces the normal status bar when it is loading.

Any idea on how to make this work programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```js
isLoading: boolean = false;

startLoading() {
  this.isLoading = true;

  // Simulate an asynchronous operation (e.g., API call, timeout, etc.)
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Once the loading is complete, set isLoading back to false
    this.isLoading = false;
  }, 2000); // Adjust the timeout value as per your requirement
}
```

```css
.loading-div {
  display: none;
  /* Add your desired styles here */
}
```

```html
<button (click)="startLoading()">Click me</button>

<div class="loading-div" [style.display]="isLoading ? 'block' : 'none'">
  Loading...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this programmatically by adding a flag or variable to track the loading status. Here's an example of how you could implement this:

1. In your component, add a boolean variable to track the loading status:

---

```
isLoading = false;
```

---

2. In your template, wrap your status bar and loading spinner in a container and use
   ***ngIf** to conditionally show them based on the loading status:

---

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <!-- Normal status bar here -->
</div>
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
  <!-- Loading spinner here -->
</div>
```

---

3. Update your "Complete" task function to set the **isLoading** flag to true before making any requests or performing any long-running tasks:

---

```
completeTask() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  // Perform task here
}
```

---

4. Once the task is complete, set the **isLoading** flag back to false to hide the loading spinner and show the normal status bar again: